# Solve recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$a_n=n^2\times a_{(n-1)}$, for $ n>0, a_0=1$

Whats the correct formula to use in this case?

I solved problem with recursion before, but they had '$+$' instead of   $'\times'$ so there is following formula to simply solve them:
$ar^n+bnr^n$.

Is there something similar, but for multiplication instead?

Comment: Compute the first terms for $\sqrt{a_n}$.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n=(n!)^2$ using induction. Try to evaluate the first few terms on your own.

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer, but it shows that the problem is somewhat stupid as $n!$ is defined literally like that, i.e. $n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1$...

Answer (score 1):

Multiply these lines together:
\begin{align}
a_n&=n^2\times a_{n-1}\\
a_{n-1}&=(n-1)^2\times a_{n-2}\\
&\dots\\
a_2&=2^2\times a_{1}\\
a_1&=1^2\times a_{0}\\
\end{align}
After canceling, we get
$$
a_n = 1^2 \cdot 2^2 \cdots n^2 a_0 = (1 \cdot 2 \cdots n)^2 = (n!)^2
$$